# How to set default publish configuration in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, configuration

I have a project in visual studio 2010 with 2 deployment type and 2 corresponding project configuration.  Right now, when I deploy, I manually set the configuration type, then click deploy.  But if possible, I would like this to be done automatically when I deploy.  Is it possible in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest Azure SDK installed then you should be able to edit your publishing settings and under the "Settings" left tab set the Configuration option. This is the configuration that will be used when you deploy with that profile.

The Azure SDK installs a much better publishing add-on, will publish to anywhere not just Azure.

[image]

Comment: But my deployment is to window server 2008, not Azure, does it work?

Comment: I answered this, "will publish to anywhere not just Azure"